# Custom "CoreLib" In .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csproj

Trying to get a custom CoreLib in .NET Core project to load in VS 2017. This was super easy in .NET Framework as all you needed was "**NoStdLib**" but with .NET Core seems like a lot more parts are needed.
I keep getting: "Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">-->
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{3DA06C3A-2E7B-4CB7-80ED-9B12916013F9}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>

    <!--<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>-->
        <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
        <AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>false</AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>
        <ExcludeMscorlibFacade>true</ExcludeMscorlibFacade>
        <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
        <NoCompilerStandardLib>true</NoCompilerStandardLib>

        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <RootNamespace>System</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>System.Private.CoreLib</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyVersion>4.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <MajorVersion>4</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>6</MinorVersion>
    <ExcludeAssemblyInfoPartialFile>true</ExcludeAssemblyInfoPartialFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Going off what System.Private.CoreLib.csproj is doing and not sure what the missing part is? Removing "**Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"**" causes part of the issue as I don't think I can have that for a custom corelib

What I'm basing this off of: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/System.Private.CoreLib.csproj

Does anyone know what the csproj settings are to get this working? I can't seem to find any good info on this.

Comment: There may be some hints here (but it’s a .net framework project): https://github.com/mosa/MOSA-Project/blob/master/Source/Mosa.Korlib/Mosa.Korlib.csproj

Comment: There is no magic in `.csproj`. All is done by build scripts. In particular `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` build script do collect sources files to `Compile` items generate appropriate command line for C# compiler and call it, and many more. If you want to remove it, then you need to replace it with something else. You need to write build script yourself or import some other build script. Currently your project file is just set of properties. And MSBuild have no clue what to do with them. It have no target to build.

Comment: @PetSerAl Why does <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> build script not allow C# 7.3 then?

Comment: @zezba9000 I have no problem using C# 7.3 features with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. I do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry I mean when I use <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> BUT remove <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework> I can compile but no C# 7.3 support. Even though <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> is enabled.

Comment: I guess a better question is are there any settings that "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" takes to allow for custom CoreLibs or frameworks?  Seems like there should be a custom "TargetFrameworkIdentifier" option or something.

Comment: `<DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>True</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>`

Comment: @PetSerAl Tnx, think this is what I'm looking for. Will confirm after I make a basic compiling core lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @PetSerAl: This does just what I needed. .NET Core fails to boot the lib (probably because my primitives, etc aren't implemented fully) but compiles all the IL I need for my project without errors.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

    <!-- Prevent .NET Core 3+ from generating exe -->
    <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>

    <!--Disable .NET Core SDK libs-->
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```